# How do I reduce guest access in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I want to make my guest users should not copy or remove files from my hard disk. Is it possible ? Kindly guide me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to put the guest users into a special group, ensure that your files are not assigned to this group and remove all rights from "World" for the respective files

example:

```
chmod o-rwx <filename>  # removes all rights for "World"
```

This should only be applied to your own files. Be sure not to change any system files, otherwise you may damage your system.